# Let $\Sigma(k)$ be the sum of all numbers whose largest proper divisor is $k$. Does an odd $k$ for which $\Sigma(k)$ is divisible by 6020 exist?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I have noticed that since the numbers whose largest proper divisor is $k$ are bounded by $k$ and $k^{2}$,the number of summands is smaller than or equal to $k^{2}-k$. $\Sigma(k)$ has to have factors of $2,2,5,301$ but I don't know how to proceed with that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $6020$ is a sum of multiples of $k$, so $6020$ is itself a multiple of $k$, that is, $k$ is a divisor of $6020$, and $6020$ has only $12$ divisors, so you could just try them all. $1,2,4,5,10,20,301,\dots$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson No 6020 is not a sum of multiples of $k$ but it divides a sum of multiples of $k$. I found some $k$ with the help of computer. Please see my answer below. Do you know some deeper number theory so that we can prove the existence of such $k$ without actually finding one?

Comment: @Neat right, I misread the question as $\Sigma_k=6020$, when it's actually $\Sigma_k$ is a multiple of $6020$.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** The answer is yes. See the results at the end of the answer.

**Original answer:**
I don't know the answer but here's some thoughts.

Suppose the smallest prime divisor of $k$ is $p_m$, the $m^{th}$ prime number. Note that $k$ is the largest proper divisor of a number $N$ if and only if $N=pk$ where $p$ is the smallest prime divisor of $N$. Therefore
$$\Sigma (k) = (2+p_2+\cdots + p_m)k$$
where $p_j$ is the $j^{th}$ prime number.

Denote $S(n):=\sum_{j=1}^n p_j$. Note that $6020=2^2 \times 5 \times 7 \times 43$.
If $k$ is odd and $6020 | \Sigma(k)$, then $4|S(m), m$ is odd.

$5|k \implies m=3, \Sigma(k)=S(3)k=10k$, but $4\nmid 10k, \Rightarrow \Leftarrow.$

Therefore $5\nmid k, 20 | S(m)$. The first such $S(m)$ is $S(23)=100$, so $7\nmid k$, $140|S(m)$.

Then we can check there is no such $S(m)$ that is a multiple of $140$ if $m\le 50$, therefore $43\nmid k$, we must have $6020|S(m)$.

I have checked the first 1000 $S(m)$'s and found no multiples of $6020$. I found [this place](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSums.html) but it doesn't help.

Maybe you can write a program to check many more primes, and ask in MathOverflow if you still can't find a $S(m)$ divisible by $6020$.

**Update**

Using some [prime number function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767408/prime-number-function-in-r) I checked all prime numbers under one million, and did find some solution. The smallest  $k$ that has the property you wanted is 197893, the $17811^{st}$ prime number.

The prime number function I used is:

```
is.prime <- function(n) n == 2L || all(n %% 2L:max(2,floor(sqrt(n))) != 0)
```

However it returns TRUE for $n=1$ so I have to exclude it from the list. Here's my program and the results:

```
N=10^6;
M=6020;
temp=rep(NA,N)

for(i in 1:N) temp[i]=as.integer(is.prime(i));

temp[1]=0; # exclude 1
pn=which(temp==1); # prime number list
pnr=pn %% M; # avoid overflow
S = cumsum(pnr); # cumulative sum

which(S %% M ==0);
```

[1] 17811 20121 25159 41437 55023 60667 67033 68509 69863 76257

```
pn[1:25] # sanity check
```

[1]  2  3  5  7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97

```
pn[17811] #  The first $k$ is 197893, the $17811^{st}$ prime number.
```

[1] 197893

```
sum(pn[1:17811]) # sanity check.
```

[1] 1675185400

```
1675185400/6020 # sanity check
```

[1] 278270

Comment: You state that $\Sigma (k) = (2+p_2+\cdots + p_m)k$ but wouldn't this only hold privided $k$ is prime? Suppose $k$ had a factor of $3$. Then if multiplied by any prime larger than $3$,$ k$ would no longer be the largest proper divisor of $N$ since $lpd(n)$ would now be equal to $N/3$ instead of $N/i$ where $i$ is a prime larger than $3$.

Comment: I have already assumed the smallest prime divisor of $k$ is $p_m$, the $m^{th}$ prime number. So for example $m=3$ then $\Sigma(k)=(2+3+5)k$. $k$ can be $25,35$, etc., not necessarily a prime number.