# Prove or disprove: for an odd $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $1010∣a(2+3+5+⋯+p_{π(a)})$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I am looking for a way to prove or disprove that $1010∣a(2+3+5+⋯+p_{π(a)})$ for an odd natural number $a$. I haven't progressed much further.

Comment: Instead of deleting and asking a new question, you should edit the old question instead. Remark: $\gcd (a,n)= a$. Also note that there is an upper bound on $p_x$.

Comment: Sorry, this version makes less sense than the first one.  Obviously the sum in question here diverges, no?  Also the header question bears little relation to the question in the body.

Comment: @lulu I am really struggling to express myself here. The sum is obviously with a certain upper limit ($x$) that is unknown. Any help making the question better would be appreciated.

Comment: To stress:  it is not generally the case that the "good" $n$ here consist of the multiples of $ap$.  That is true for the case $p=2, a=3$ but it is false for, say, $p=2, a=5$.  For that example, $n=30$ is not good since, for that example, the least prime divisor would indeed be $p=2$ but the second largest divisor is $3$, not $5$.

Comment: My comment to the prior version of this post included my guess as to what you were asking.  It was a pretty wild guess, far from what you actually wrote, but it seems (to me at least) that it is a coherent problem.  To be clear:  I don't know the answer to my question.

Comment: @lulu $a$ is not necessarily a prime number. For $n=30, p=2$ and $a=15$.

Comment: I did not say that $a$ was prime.   But, in your example,$a=3$, not $15$.

Comment: My take on this question is (since a very similar question was posted recently) is that, for a fixed $a$ (say $15$), we have a set of $n$ such that the $n=ap$ is satisfied for some $p$. (This set is $\{30, 45\}$, with the sum $75 = 15(2+3)$). Also the question should be phrased as "whether there exists an odd $a$ such that 'the sum' is divisible by $1010$" (instead of "for all"), or else the answer is trivial.

Comment: @lulu If I understand correctly, the divisors of $30$ are $1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30$. $p$ is the smallest prime divisor, $2$, and $a$ is the second largest number from the divisors, that is $15$. $a = \frac{n}{p}$

Comment: Can you show us an explicit example of what you have in mind? Because if I fix the value of $a$ to be $3$, then the only $n$ I see for which $n=ap$ with $p$ the smallest prime divisor of $n$ are $n=6$ (with $p=2$) and $n=9$ (with $p=3$). These values of $n$ sum to $15$, which certainly isn't divisible by $1010$. So what am I missing?

Comment: Ah, for whatever reason I was reading it as requiring that $a$ be the second$\textit{ smallest }$divisor.  My error.

Comment: @BarryCipra there isn't really much information given to me in this exercise. The only thing I know about $a$ is that it's an odd number. There could be just one $a$ fitting the set rules, surely not all possible $a$'s work

Comment: Oddly, my version of your question still makes sense.  For fixed $a$ we can still look at the sum of the first $k$ good $n$ and ask if there is a $k$ for which that sum is a multiple of $1010$.  For $a=1$ this comes down to:  is there a $k$ such that the sum of the first $k$ primes is divisible by $1010$?

Comment: @lulu $a$ cannot be $1$. $a \geq p$ and since $p$ is prime, $a \geq 2$

Comment: Why?  What if $n$ is a prime?  Then the divisors of $n$ are $1$ and $n$.  The least prime dividing $n$ is $n$ and the second largest divisor of $n$ is $1$.  Hence $a=1$ for all primes.   You never said that $a≥p$.  If you left off information, please add it back.

Comment: More broadly, however, I think we are all just blindly guessing at what the question might mean.  That's not a great idea.  Why not just seek clarification from whomever set the problem?  A clear numerical example would help a lot.

Comment: @lulu you're probably right, the further this discussion goes, the less I seem to understand the question myself.

Comment: Well, I confused matters by mistakenly thinking that $a$ was the second smallest divisor instead of the second largest.  For most values of $a$ there are only finitely many $n$ that have $a$ has the second largest factor.  For $a=3$, say, the only examples are $n=6$ and $9$.  Of course $6+9$ is not divisible by $1010$ so I don't think this example helps much.

Comment: @lulu the $a$ obviously has to be way larger than $3$

Comment: @lulu, player3236 suggests a rewording in which we're only asking if there is *some* odd $a$ for which the sum is divisible by $1010$. I would express this as looking for an odd number $a$ such that $$1010\mid a(2+3+5+\cdots+p_{\pi(a)})$$ in which case looking at the sequence of sums of primes becomes relevant.

Comment: @BarryCipra that's a good way to word it, I am going to edit the original post

Comment: @BarryCipra  Well, that seems like numerical work.  Taking $a$ to be an odd multiple of $505$ we see that we just want the sum of the primes less than $a$ to be even, which is the same as asking that $\pi(a)$ be odd. That fails for $505$ and for $3\times 505$ but succeeds with $5\times 505$.  No idea if a smaller value of $a$ works, but this proves existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

It is not clear what the question is asking. One interpretation follows from the remark that, for $a>1$, there are only finitely many values of $n$ for which $a$ might be the second largest divisor.  Indeed, the good $n$ are $\{2a, 3a, \cdots, p_{\pi(a)}a\}$  where, as usual, $\pi(a)$ denotes the number of primes less than or equal to  $a$ and, for $i\in \mathbb N$, $p_i$ denotes the $i^{th}$ prime.

We then interpret the question as:  Is there an odd number $a$ such that $1010$ divides the sum $a(2+\cdots +p_{\pi(a)})$?

The answer to that is yes.

To construct an example we consider the odd multiples of $505$.  Indeed, for such $a$, we only need the sum of the primes to be even.  That is equivalent to requiring that $\pi(a)$ be odd and we check (numerically) that this is the case for $a=5\times 505$.  Of course, there may be a smaller value of $a$ that works, but any example suffices to prove existence.

Note on the calculation:  I used [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5Bprimepi%28%282n%2B1%29*505%29%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C10%7D%5D), but the numbers here are small enough that a table of the primes would suffice.  Note that $\pi(5\times 505)=369$ so your table need only cover the first few hundred primes.

I stress that we are not sure we are reading the problem correctly, but the above interpretation and calculation represents our best guess.

Several users were involved in this work, notably @player3236 and @BarryCipra.  I will, accordingly, post this as a Community solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity I wrote a program to find the smallest $a$. It's very little work because I answered [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3922916/let-sigmak-be-the-sum-of-all-numbers-whose-largest-proper-divisor-is-k-d/) a few days ago and it also involves [Prime Sums](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSums.html) and a bit programming.

Anyway here's the program and the output:

```
is.prime <- function(n) n == 2L || all(n %% 2L:max(2,floor(sqrt(n))) != 0)

N=10^4;
M=1010;
temp=rep(NA,N)

for(i in 1:N) temp[i]=as.integer(is.prime(i));

temp[1]=0; # exclude 1
pn=which(temp==1); # prime number list

pcf=rep(NA,N); # prime counting function
for(i in 1:N) pcf[i] = sum(pn<=i)

pnr=pn %% M; # avoid overflow

S = cumsum(pnr); # cumulative sum

P = rep(NA, N);
P[1]=1;
for(a in 2:N)
{
    P[a]=a*S[pcf[a]];
}
indx = which((P %% M==0))
indx[which(indx%%2==1)]
```

[1] 2525 4545 4949 6363 7575 8181 8585 9191 9805 9975 9985 9995

You can see that $2525=5\cdot 505$ is indeed the smallest, followed by another multiple of $505$.

Comment: Thanks for doing this (+1).  Makes sense that $5\times 505$ be minimal, I'd say, since getting that factor of $101$ in the prime sum is a big ask.  Still, you never know till you check.